# Can two pairs of spaces have the same cohomology rings and their products have different ones?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Is there known example of $CW$-complexes $X$, $Y$, $X'$ and $Y'$, such that their cohomology rings (with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$) are isomorphic: 
$$H^*(X)\simeq H^*(X'), H^*(Y)\simeq H^*(Y'),$$
but their products have different cohomology rings: 
$$H^*(X\times Y)\ne H^*(X'\times Y')?$$

maybe this conjecture is false by some obvious construction with $\smile$-product, but i'm failing to invent it.

Comment: Doesn't the K\:unneth formula imply that $H^{\ast}(X \times X') \cong H^{\ast}(X) \otimes H^{\ast}(X')$ (at least with coefficients in a field)?

Comment: @user45878 yes, thank you. with coefficients in a field it's correct, but i'm interested only in $\mathbb Z$-coefficients

Comment: I think it might still work out in general (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem)

Comment: @user45878 i think not, because Künneth formula says nothing about multiplication on $\mathrm{Ext}$-summands. or i have missed some details?

Comment: No, I think you are right. Künneth only says something about the module structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hatcher describes a counter example in his book on page 307 (example 3E.6). He explicitly gives finite CW complexes $X,X'$ and $Y$ such that $H^*(X\times Y;\mathbb{Z})\not \cong H^*(X'\times Y;\mathbb{Z})$ as rings, but $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong H^*(X';\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: thank you! and, do you know, does this example work when we replace the products $X\times Y$ by smash-products $X\wedge Y$?

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev: I just remembered that I saw a counterexample somewhere and found it again. I did not really think too much about the example. Unfortunately I therefore can't answer your question.